# How to remove readonly attribute from form input element

Tags: forms

I have a form with date picker. Its a view exposed search form. i need to remove readonly attribute of this field to edit the field. I tried jQuery code `jQuery("#edit-date-filter-value-datepicker-popup-0").attr("readonly", false);` but didnt work. Can i do it in my view?

`<input id="edit-date-filter-value-datepicker-popup-0" class="form-text hasDatepicker date-popup-init" type="text" maxlength="200" size="20" value="" name="date_filter[value][date]" placeholder="YYYY-MM-DD" readonly="readonly">`

Comment: Have you considered that simply removing it might cause errors? Module that created this element clearly is not ready to receive any value from it. Have you already updated all handlers to make sure making it writable will have valid and expected effect?

Comment: Is there any way to remove it using views?. No error will occur when readonly is removed. I will check the condition whether the input date format is correct.

Comment: By default its readlony. But when the user clicks on textfield, he should be able to add date manually.